# Inject request attribute from request to spring controller methods

Tags: java, spring, inject

I have some spring @RestControllers methods that I would like to inject with a value that comes with every request as a request attribute(containing the user) something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/jobs")
public class JobsController {
     // Option 1 get user from request attribute as prop somehow
     private String userId = "user1";

    // Option 2 inject into method using aspect or something else
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Jobs>> getJobs() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
       // currentUser is injected 
       this.getJobs(currentUser);
}
```

I know I can do that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/jobs")
public class JobsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Jobs>> getJobs(HttpServletRequest request) throws ResourceNotFoundException { 
       String currentUser = null;
       if (request.getAttribute("subject") != null) {
           currentUser = request.getAttribute("subject").toString();
       }
       this.getJobs(currentUser);
}
```

But that would require me to add this code at every method in my program, which seems to me, to be a really bad practice.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

If the answer do require aspect, a code example will be much appreciated since I only read about it, but never actually did something with aspect.

**Update**
The code i suggested can be simplified using this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/jobs")
public class JobsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Jobs>> getJobs(@Value("#{request.getAttribute('subject')}" String currentUser) throws ResourceNotFoundException { 
       this.getJobs(currentUser);
}
```

But still require me to add that parameter at every method.
Can this parameter be injected to every method somehow?

Comment: Have you read [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader)? You don't need an aspect as it is supported out-of-the-box... Don't make things more complex then needed.

Comment: I can't seem to understand how is it out-of-the-box? I need to put this piece of code on every method i have, i would like to avoid it.

Comment: If it is JWT then I strongly suggest instead of setting an attribute integrate with the request properly and use the principal. That way you can do `getPrincipal` on the request or simply add the `Principal` to the method signature. If you use Spring Security for decoding the JWT you would get this support for free (well you need the configuration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Filter` to populate a `ThreadLocal<String>` variable that stores that attribute:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    ContextHolder.setSubject(request.getAttribute('subject'));
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    ContextHolder.removeSubject();
  }
}


public class ContextHolder {

  private static final ThreadLocal<String> SUBJECT = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
      return "empty";
    }
  };

  public static void setSubject(String subject) {
    SUBJECT.set(subject);
  }

  public static String getSubject() {
    return SUBJECT.get();
  }

  public static void removeSubject() {
    SUBJECT.remove();
  }
}
```

The filter will be configured to intercept all requests and populate the `SUBJECT` variable. By using a `ThreadLocal`, you make sure that each thread has it's own `subject` value. You can now get that value anywhere in your application by calling `ContextHolder.getSubject()`:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<List<Jobs>> getJobs(HttpServletRequest request) throws ResourceNotFoundException { 
    this.getJobs(ContextHolder.getSubject());
  }
```

You will also have to register the `Filter` in the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In case you had multiple attributes, you could use a `ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>` variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just add `@RequestAttribute` in your rest **contorller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/yourpath")

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getAll(
            @RequestAttribute(value = "yourAttribute") Object
```

yourAttribute......

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know about attributes then you should check out spring's [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation. You'd use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Jobs>> getJobs(@RequestParam("subject") String currentUser) throws ResourceNotFoundException { 
   this.getJobs(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: The @Header attribute doesn't work for me since the data is at a request attribute. And the reason i get the user like that is that i use jwt, and before my controller there is a filter that takes the user from the token and put it on the request.

Comment: What i needed was @Value("#{request.getAttribute('subject')}" but that still require duplication for every method. Iv'e updated the question, thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try @RequestAttribute first? Spring should handle this for you directly without having to resort to spel.